# Hyperledger Caliper tutorial for Composer network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-caliper

I want to execute a performance evaluation test on a deployed Hyperledger Composer business network using Hyperledger Caliper.

Into the official documentation there is a section for the [Composer configuration](https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/docs/Composer_Configuration.html) but I think that it's not very user friendly for those approaching this framework for the first time and I cannot find a better basic step-by-step tutorial for configuring and running an evaluation test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Check that all the prerequisites are installed:**

- NodeJS 8 (LTS), 9, or 10 (LTS) *higher versions are not supported as
  the dependancy chain does not permit this*
- node-gyp
- Docker
- Docker-compose

### **Build Caliper:**

- Run `npm install` in Caliper root folder to install base dependencies locally
- Run `npm run repoclean` in Caliper root folder to ensure that all the packages are clean
- Run `npm run bootstrap` to bootstrap the packages in the Caliper repository. This will install all package dependancies and link any cross dependancies. It will take some time to finish installation. If it is interrupted by ctrl+c, please recover the file package.json first and then run npm run bootstrap again.

Do not run any of the above commands with `sudo`, as it will cause the bootstrap process to fail

### **Install the Caliper CLI**

Execute the following command from the `packages/caliper-tests-integration` directory:

```
npm run e2e_install
```

### Run a Sample Benchmark

from `caliper/packages/caliper-samples/` run

```
caliper benchmark run -c benchmark/composer/config.yaml -n network/fabric-v1.3/2org1peercouchdb/composer.json -w ../caliper-samples/
```

where the parameters means:

```
-w : path to a workspace directory (required)
-c : relative path from the workspace to the benchmark configuration file (required).
-n : relative path from the workspace to the config file of the blockchain network under test (required).
```

To create tests for your Business Network you need to modify the `config.yaml` and `composer.json` files. You also have to create a `.js` file where you need to implement the test to be runned, and specify the path to this file in the *callback* section of `config.yaml` file.

For more informations check https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/docs/1_Getting_Started.html

Comment: Note, that the setup process has been simplified since Caliper was published on npm/DockerHub: https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/vLatest/installing-caliper/