# How to test my own business network made on Hyperledger Composer using Hyperledger Caliper

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

I'm currently working on performance benchmarking using Hyperledger Caliper.

I have tried several samples but it seems that the structure of sample benchmarks are different from that of a business network made on Hyperledger Composer.
Looks like model file and script file are all reproduced into one javascript file as a benchmark.

Could anyone tell me how to test my own business network made on Hyperledger Composer?
Or, Should I reproduce my business network into one javascript file?

I looked at the official website (https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/)
But, it seems that it is not updated because codes on the website don't work.

Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142705/hyperledger-caliper-tutorial-for-composer-network